# How to draw a moving line on android camera?

Tags: android, camera

I'd like to draw a moving line on a the camera for waiting the end of a process. For the moment I have this piece of code :

```
 public class OcrGraphic extends GraphicOverlay.Graphic {

    OcrGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlayt) {
        super(overlay);
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
         //draw line
    }
}
```

The issue is that I don't want to draw the line only once but I want to create something like a thread in the purpose of moving the line (up and down) during a long process.

Here is the XML I have :

```
    <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:minHeight="5dp" />

    </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>
```

The 'camereSourcePreview' tag comes from the google vision API.

Answer (score 1):

The Animation framework is here for you.

Create a line in your layout xml file. Something like this

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="#cccccc"
  android:id="@+id/line"/>
```

then create an animation resource in your anim resources folder.

```
<set android:repeatMode="reverse"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="300"
    />
```

And in your code, get the view to animate and animate with AnimationUtils

```
View line= (View) findViewById(R.id.line);
Animation upDown= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.up_down_anim);
line.startAnimation(upDown);
```

Then to finish the animation you can call (not sure here)

```
line.getAnimation().cancel();
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. When I add the view in the xml, even if I set the height with 1dp, it takes all the screen. I update my preview post to show you my xml file.

Comment: You might have to wrap the line into a FrameLayout. I've never used the CameraSourcePreview but I can see it extends ViewGroup but I don't know how it behaves as a layout.

Comment: It doesn't work. Finally, I use SurfaceView to overlay the camera.